# passing argument through css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

So I have a code which looks like this:

```
<div className="site-col-1">
   content 1
</div>
<div className="site-col-2">
  content 2
</div>
```

And the css file looks like this...

```
.site-col-1 {
    grid-column: span 1;
}

.site-col-2 {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.site-col-3 {
   grid-column: span 3;
}
```

Is there a way to just pass the number as an argument from the div rather than have a long css file. Something along these lines:

```
.site-col-ARG {
  grid-column: span ARG
}
```

Comment: The output will be a long CSS file anyway. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to shorten my Css code from having site-col-1, site-col-2, site-col-3... etc to just have one property as site-col-? and then passing 1, 2 or 3 inline to get grid-column: span ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [styled component](https://styled-components.com/) with react js to achieve the same.

```js
const Div = styled.div`
  /* Change the grid-column value as per the provided props value */
  grid-column: ${props => props.value};
`;

//In your .jsx file
render(
  <div>
    <Div value="1">
      content 1
    </Div>
    <Div value="2">
      content 2
    </Div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are saying is half-true, ie, in HTML-file where you write the code, then by making use of some JS_Template library like `Handlebars`, `Mustache`, etc. this is possible.

Even, in React you can do so --- but only in the file where you might add templates with the help of `JavaScript` (or incase of react via `JSX`).

**CSS:**

Now, you are getting over-ambitious and trying to do the same in a plain-CSS file. Answer is **NO**. This is NOT possible, in CSS

**SASS:**

Yes, if you are using a CSS-pre-processor, then you might use `Loops`. Using them, (only if you are using a CSS-pre-processor), then you might write something like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
.site-col-#{$i} {
  grid-column: span #{$i}
}
}
```

Check here: https://codebeautify.org/scss-to-css-converter (choose to convert scss and NOT sass).

[image]